# Django South - Migrate From Python Code

Tags: python, django, django-south

Is it possible to run a migration from Python code? I don't want to (actually I cannot) use the terminal command:

```
venv/bin/python src/manage.py migrate myapp
```

I need to run it from Python code as part of my business logic on a dynamically created database.

This is what I have so far:

```
db_name = uuid.uuid4()
from settings.local import DATABASES
new_database = {}
new_database['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.mysql'
new_database['NAME'] = db_name
new_database['USER'] = DATABASES["default"]["USER"]
new_database['PASSWORD'] = DATABASES["default"]["PASSWORD"]
new_database['HOST'] = DATABASES["default"]["HOST"]
new_database['PORT'] = DATABASES["default"]["PORT"]
import settings
database_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
settings.DATABASES[database_id] = new_database
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command('migrate', 'catalogue', database=database_id)
```

But I get:

```
KeyError: '28a4eb10-91e4-4de8-8a74-15d72f8245ef'
```

Comment: Could you explain _why_ you cannot invoke shell commands?

Comment: @Tadeck Because the database I want to run migration on is not in my config file. It is a dynamically created and destroyed database. I create and then drop it as part of my business logic.

Comment: You can also supply the path to the settings (config) file like that: `--settings=my_config_file.py`.

Comment: @Tadeck is it possible without a config file? Cannot I just use database name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can. Assuming it is called from within Django app:

```
from django.core.management import call_command

call_command('migrate', 'myapp')
```

Comment: Thanks. How to specify which database it should run on? I have multiple databases.

Comment: @RichardKnop: This should be in your settings file, so you can either separate it into different fiels or try to create your own command that overrides `settings` part (or selects the database from the list of configured ones) and calls the `migrate` command in the way I mentioned.

Comment: I have tried call_command('migrate', 'catalogue', database=database_id) but that doesn't work.

Comment: @RichardKnop: I am sorry, it is too localized now. If you have multiple databases, the implementation depends on the reason. If you want to have them all at once available, use dictionary `DATABASES` with separate keys for separate databases. In case you want different sites, use separate `settings` files. Also do `from django.conf import settings`, not `import settings` - the first one is lazy. Next, you did not say where `KeyError` is generated (is it `from settings.local import DATABASES`, `settings.DATABASES[database_id]` or `call_command()` call? we do not know)...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you are having is that you are configuring the new database in runtime. So, the configuration you change in runtime is over the process/thread you are hitting with that code. The settings dict is immutable and you can not change it in runtime (see django docs).

I am not sure, but very probably the setting dict used by call_command is a copy from the original dict loaded from the settings configuration and that is why you get the key error (there is no new config in there).

By the way, is published that doing changes over settings configuration in runtime is not recommended by the django community.